# Save_and_open_page not picking up scss markup

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

Just upgraded a RoR 3.0 project to 3.2. I've moved the CSS assets to the asset pipeline and now using SASS.  My Rspec request specs still pass, but when I throw in a save_and_open_page statement, the resulting page doesn't have any CSS stylings.  The HTML rendering is all accurate, explaining the passing tests.

Any config ideas?

Comment: Known issue. See https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/pull/609

Answer (score 2):

You can use `capybara-screenshot` gem for debugging.

It will take a screenshot of the page you want to debug.

Install the gem and use `screen_shot_and_open_image` instead of `save_and_open_page`