# save_and_open_page has stopped serving up my css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara

My testing setup was working very nicely serving up pages correctly formatted with css whenever I called `save_and_open_page` from within a test. I then set up some javascript tests and made a few changes to my setup (sorry I can't detail them all - I haven't documented things well enough). After making changes I now get unformatted html in the browser when I call `save_and_open_page`.

Here's my spec/spec_helper.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do

  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'
  require 'capybara/rspec'
  require 'factory_girl'
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
    config.add_setting(:seed_tables)
    config.seed_tables = %w(notifications drug_names drug_modes drug_prefs db_tables db_columns column_values)
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
    config.before(:suite) do
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation, {except: config.seed_tables}
    end
    config.before(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.start
    end
    config.after(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
    config.include Features::SessionHelpers, type: :feature
    config.order = "random"
  end
  Spork.each_run do
    FactoryGirl.reload
  end
end
```

I have the following gems installed in my test environment;

```
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.0'
gem 'guard-rspec', '2.4.1'
gem 'rb-fsevent', '0.9.3'
gem 'terminal-notifier-guard', '1.5.3'
gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'
gem 'spork', '0.9.2'
gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
gem 'timecop', '0.5.9.2'
gem 'launchy', '2.2.0'
gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'shoulda', '3.3.2'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'database_cleaner', '0.9.1'
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.32.1'
```

Any clues as to what I've done to stop this from working properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was removed from Capybara, in [pull 609](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/pull/609)

Jnicklas:

> I am making an executive decision here by virtue of my status as
>   Benevolent Dictator for Life of Capybara:
>
> Asset rewriting has got to go. It is seriously the worst part of the
>   entire Capybara code base. It's a terrible hack which has never worked
>   right in the first place and the slim benefit it gives us can easily
>   be achieved by superior debugging methods, like running the same test
>   in Selenium and halting execution via e.g. sleep, gets or binding.pry.
>
> I'm sorry if this annoys some of you, but it's my job to make the
>   tough decisions about what goes in and what stays out. If I don't do
>   that job and simply accept everything, we will not end up with a good
>   result. So I hope that you can accept this decision even though you
>   may disagree with it.

As per [Save_and_open_page not picking up scss markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356398/save-and-open-page-not-picking-up-scss-markup) you could consider making screenshots with the `capybara-screenshot`-gem.

This gem will introduce `save_and_open_screenshot`.

However, as jnicklas mentions in the discussion in the pull-request there is a good reason to not want this feature at all:

> ...because RackTest doesn't have CSS and JS, so now you're seeing the page differently from how Capybara would

Answer (score 15):

Just an FYI, save_and_open_page works courtesy of the wonderful people of these 2 links.
This is what I have at the bottom of my spec_helper.rb to make it work

```
# to allow CSS and Javascript to be loaded when we use save_and_open_page, the
# development server must be running at localhost:3000 as specified below or
# wherever you want. See original issue here:
#https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/pull/609
# and final resolution here:
#https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/pull/958
Capybara.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000"
```

enjoy and thank you sdhull and jnicklas and all who worked on it

Hani

Comment: Tip:  Make sure you have your __DEVELOPMENT__ server running, like the code comments say!  Or it will appear to do nothing.  :)  (I read it too quickly the first time.)